# MySQL problem with multiple-tables

Tags: sql, mysql

newb question there. Having MySQL database/tables structure below:

```
CREATE DATABASE `dbTest`

CREATE  TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `dbTest`.`tbUser` (

  `UserId` INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT ,

  `Username` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL ,

  PRIMARY KEY (`UserId`) )

ENGINE = InnoDB

CREATE  TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `dbTest`.`tbTransactionType` (

  `TypeId` INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT ,

  `Name` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL ,

  PRIMARY KEY (`TypeId`) )

ENGINE = InnoDB

CREATE  TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `dbTest`.`tbTransaction` (

  `TransactionId` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT ,

  `UserId` INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL ,

  `TransactionType` INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL ,

  `Balance` DOUBLE NOT NULL ,

  `Date` DATETIME NOT NULL ,

  PRIMARY KEY (`TransactionId`) ,

  INDEX `FK_tbTransaction_tbUser_UserId` (`UserId` ASC) ,

  INDEX `FK_tbTransaction_tbTransactionType_TransactionId` (`TransactionType` ASC) ,

  CONSTRAINT `FK_tbTransaction_tbUser_UserId`

    FOREIGN KEY (`UserId` )

    REFERENCES `dbTest`.`tbUser` (`UserId` )

    ON DELETE NO ACTION

    ON UPDATE NO ACTION,

  CONSTRAINT `FK_tbTransaction_tbTransactionType_TransactionId`

    FOREIGN KEY (`TransactionType` )

    REFERENCES `dbTest`.`tbTransactionType` (`TypeId` )

    ON DELETE NO ACTION

    ON UPDATE NO ACTION)

ENGINE = InnoDB

INSERT INTO `dbTest`.`tbUser` (`UserId`, `Username`) VALUES ('1', 'User1');
INSERT INTO `dbTest`.`tbTransactionType` (`TypeId`, `Name`) VALUES ('1', 'Deposite');
INSERT INTO `dbTest`.`tbTransactionType` (`TypeId`, `Name`) VALUES ('2', 'Withdraw');

INSERT INTO `dbTest`.`tbTransaction` (`TransactionId`, `UserId`, `TransactionType`, `Balance`, `Date`) VALUES (NULL, '1', '1', '200', NOW())
INSERT INTO `dbTest`.`tbTransaction` (`TransactionId`, `UserId`, `TransactionType`, `Balance`, `Date`) VALUES (NULL, '1', '2', '100', NOW())
INSERT INTO `dbTest`.`tbTransaction` (`TransactionId`, `UserId`, `TransactionType`, `Balance`, `Date`) VALUES (NULL, '1', '1', '20', NOW())
INSERT INTO `dbTest`.`tbTransaction` (`TransactionId`, `UserId`, `TransactionType`, `Balance`, `Date`) VALUES (NULL, '1', '2', '10', NOW())
```

I would like to get the **last entry of each type** of transaction for the UserId 1

This is my SQL query:

```
SELECT U.Username, TT.Name, T.Balance, T.Date
FROM tbUser U
INNER JOIN tbTransaction T ON T.UserId = U.UserId
INNER JOIN tbTransactionType TT ON TT.TypeId = T.TransactionType
WHERE U.UserId = 1
```

And the result is:

```
Username    Name        Balance Date
User1   Deposite    200     2010-11-26 23:11:40
User1   Deposite    20      2010-11-26 23:14:56
User1   Withdraw    100     2010-11-26 23:11:58
User1   Withdraw    10      2010-11-26 23:14:56
```

When I would like to get something like:

```
Username    Name        Balance Date
User1       Deposite    20      2010-11-26 23:14:56
User1       Withdraw    10      2010-11-26 23:14:56
```

I'm sure the solution isn't that hard but I can't figure out right now...

I've also tried a `GROUP BY TT.TypeId` with no success.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this should do it, and it won't be an issue if you add more transaction types. However, I haven't quite tested bc I don't exactly have an "isomorphic" (probably not strictly the correct term) set of tables handy to test on.  Please let me know even if you're solved, I'm curious.

```
SELECT U.Username, TT.Name, T.Balance, T.Date
FROM tbUser U
INNER JOIN tbTransaction T ON T.UserId = U.UserId
INNER JOIN tbTransactionType TT ON TT.TypeId = T.TransactionType
WHERE U.UserId = 1 AND 
       T2.Date = (SELECT MAX(T2.date) 
                 FROM tbTransaction T2 WHERE 
                 T2.UserID = U.UserId, T2.TransactionType = T.TransactionType)
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. I tried that one too. But it wont work if the entries in `tbTransaction` aren't in the good order. I mean, two deposite then a withdraw are made. Also, what happens if more `TransactionType` are added? That `Limit 2` won't work.

Comment: so you do want the last two of each type?  thats not whats your sample answer reflects - it is either the last two total, or the last one of each type

Comment: Oops! sorry. The last entry of each Transaction Type. I edited the question.

Comment: @Cybrix - I see you've found a good answer, glad you got it.  Still, please take a look - I'm curios about this.

Comment: This works too! I am now unsure which one is better (speed). Yours is easier to understand though.

Comment: forget it you didnt need to do all that, if you had a working answer thats great.  thanks for letting me know thats all i wanted.

Comment: looks like conceptually astander's and mine are pretty much equivalent, tho i have to wonder if his GROUP BY's are extraneous

Answer (score 1):

How about something like this

```
SELECT  lt.Username, 
        lt.Name, 
        T.Balance, 
        T.Date 
FROM    (
            SELECT  u.UserID,
                    u.UserName,
                    T.TransactionType,
                    TT.Name,
                    MAX(t.Date) LastDate
            FROM    tbUser U INNER JOIN 
                    tbTransaction T ON T.UserId = U.UserId INNER JOIN 
                    tbTransactionType TT ON TT.TypeId = T.TransactionType
            GROUP BY    u.UserID,
                        u.UserName,
                        T.TransactionType,
                        TT.Name
        ) lt INNER JOIN 
        tbTransaction T ON  T.UserId = lt.UserId
                        AND t.TransactionType = lt.TransactionType
                        AND t.Date = lt.LastDate 
WHERE   lt.UserId = 1
```

The first sub select will return a list of all users and transaction types, and the last transaction date per.

You can then JOIN back to the Transactions table using this information to retrieve the balances.

Comment: It's working! But is there a way to do it without sub-selects? Tell me if I'm wrong but will the server have trouble running that query as the tbTransaction grows?

Comment: I dont think you will be able to do iw without the subselect, unless you have a predetemined number of transaction types to allow for a clever LIMIT statement. If your indexing is correct, it should not be to great a problem.

Answer (score 0):

> I would like to get the last two entry
>   of each type of transaction for the
>   UserId 1

If this is what you want then you do have that in your question, unless I misunderstood the question.

You want last two entries for each `TransactionType`:

-Deposite: you have the `Transaction` for $200 and $20

-Withdraw: you have the `Transaction` for $100 and $10

what exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: Yes sorry about that. I edited it: I would like to get the last entry of each type of transaction for the UserId 1